# Pushing dynamic content using GTM element visibility trigger and data layer

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

Google Tag Manager's Element Visibility Trigger appears to be a rather excellent way of tracking whether an element has appeared within the viewport, using a class or ID.

The standard reporting appears to pull back data something like this

[image: gtm.elementVisibility]

However what I would like to do is to be able to use the trigger to detect and report items in a dynamically created list. For instance the element would be triggered based on its class which is shared by all the other elements in the list, each element may be populated with specific data to be pulled from a database eg: name, product ID, price etc.

Currently this has been done using the Custom Event Trigger, but this reports all elements on the page whether they are loaded or not.

What I would like to know is whether the element visibility trigger is the right thing for this and if so, how can I manipulate it to do what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Probably yes.

You'd use the CSS Selector and select via the class name for your dynamically created items.

In the "When to fire this trigger" option you would select "Every time an element appears".

Finally you would set the "listen to DOM changes" option. This checks every time the DOM is manipulated (e.g. by inserting your list element) if the other criteria in the trigger are now matched.

Note that GTM warn that there may be a performance penalty for using that option (since this runs on every DOM manipulation). So you probably don't want to do this a lot.

Comment: Thank you @Eike Pierstoff. These are the settings I currently have and brings back the results as in the screengrab I included. Unless I have missed something of course. What I would like to be able to do is return specific data held on a database that  relates to each element as it loads.

Comment: Ah, I didn't get get. You can create a datalayer variable for gtm.element (which will return the element that just has become visible), and use getAttribute for standard attributes or dataset if you are using custom data attributes to read properties of that element.